# What is the phase-amplitude numerical method?

Tags: interactions, numerical-method

What is the phase-amplitude numerical method?

I heard its used to calculate long range interactions numerically, but I cannot find any papers discussing its method of implementation.

Comment: Would [dsp.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: @Qmechanic Not sure. I think its used to calculate either long range lattice interactions, or maybe molecular ionization interactions.